# want to pull out data from a specific field of a pdf and write them into a new pdf

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have one .pdf file that contains data field in every page. But the fields are not identified. I want to pull/extract those unidentified field data from the pdf and insert them into a new pdf. These data are not English language . Its Bangla language.

How can i manage this in Acrobat javascript api??

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "not identified fields"?

Comment: actually i have to post a image to make you understand but i am new and not so professional to gain points and post image.

Answer (score 0):

If by "not identified" you mean you do not have the names of fields, you can access them via the document's `getNthFieldName()` method. The following would store the names of all of the fields in a document in an array:

```
fieldNames = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++)
{
    fieldsNames.push(this.getNthFieldName(i));
}
```

You can then access the fields to get their values, field properties, etc.

Without more information about what is being moved to the new PDF, I can't provide further guidance.